# Sitecore Scalabilty Settings - Publishing instance on Azure cloud Service

Tags: publishing, azure

I have two different cloud services for CM and CD environment. In scalability setting we need to mention Publishing Instance (setting name is **Publishing.PublishingInstance**). Since I am using Cloud services for deployment, Post OS updates machine name keeps changing.

How we can set the value of publishing instance to make sure it will not be impacted even if machine name changes?

Environment Details :-

Sitecore Authoring - **Cloud Service "A"** with one web role instance

Sitecore Delivery - **Cloud Service "B"** with Two Web roles instance

Sitecore Version - **Sitecore 8.1 update -2**

**Update**

Do we really need publishing instance if we have only one CM server?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a publishing instance, the instance where the editor clicks "publish" (the 1 CM you have) will be the one publishing.

You have to specify the publishing instance only when you want to have a specific server, other than the CM, handling the publishing.